# почему иероглифы при отправке данных

Tags: java

Я сделал сервер и клиент. При отправке с клиента на сервер каких-либо данных, сначала приходят какие-то иероглифы потом текст. Как убрать иероглифы? Вот код:

Клиент

```
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class pro {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        Socket socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1",80);

        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        oos.writeObject("KKKK");
    }
}
```

Сервер

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.io.OutputStream;

public class networking {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
      ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(80);

      Socket accept = server.accept();
        InputStream inputStream = accept.getInputStream();
        OutputStream outputStream = accept.getOutputStream();

        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(outputStream);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"utf8"));
        int i=-1;
        while((i=inputStream.read())!=-1){
         System.out.println((char)i);
        }
        //oos.writeUTF("<html><body><h1>Hello from Habrahabr</h1></body></html>");
        //oos.flush();
    }
}
```

Comment: Везде, где ожидаешь текст, а получаешь иероглифы, вопросы, квадратики и т.п. - это проблемы с кодировками. [Вот здесь](http://www.skipy.ru/technics/encodings.html) можно почитать. Лучше это знать, чем каждый раз в ступор впадать. Я как-то день просидел пытаясь понять почему после редактирования блокнотом файла, программа перестает этот файл читать. Оказалось из-за [BOM символов](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%80_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8_%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Честно говоря не знаю зачем вы пытаетесь считать `char`

Можно использовать пару способов.

1) Это `DataInputStream` на сервере и `DataOutputStream` на клиенте и использовать `readUTF` и `writeUTF` соответственно.

**КЛИЕНТ:**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Client {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, InterruptedException{
        InetAddress host = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
        Socket socket = null;

        socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 80);

        OutputStream sout = socket.getOutputStream();
        // Конвертируем потоки в другой тип, чтоб легче обрабатывать текстовые сообщения.    
        DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(sout);
        String line = null;
        line = "Здаровааа exit";
        out.writeUTF(line);

        out.flush();
    }
}
```

**СЕРВЕР**

```
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;


public class Networking {
    private static ServerSocket server;
    private static int port = 80;

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException{
        server = new ServerSocket(port);
        while(true){
            System.out.println("Waiting for client request\n");

            Socket socket = server.accept();

            InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
            // Опять конвертируем в другой тип
            DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(is);                
            String message = din.readUTF(); 
            System.out.println("The dumb client just sent me this line : " + message + "\n");

            socket.close();
            if (message.contains("exit"))
                break;
        }

       System.out.println("Shutting down Socket server!!");
       server.close();
    }
}
```

---

2) Раз мы работаем `ObjectOutputStream`, то может на сервере использовать `ObjectInputStream` И `writeObject`/`readObject` соответственно?

**КЛИЕНТ**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Client {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, InterruptedException{
        Socket socket = null;
        ObjectOutputStream oos = null;

        socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 80);
        oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

        oos.writeObject("Приветик чел exit");

        oos.close();
    }
}
```

**СЕРВЕР**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Networking {
    private static ServerSocket server;
    private static int port = 80;

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException{
        server = new ServerSocket(port);
        while(true){
            System.out.println("Waiting for client request\n");

            Socket socket = server.accept();
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            String message = (String) ois.readObject();
            System.out.println("Message Received: " + message + "\n");

            ois.close();
            socket.close();
            if (message.contains("exit"))
                break;
        }

       System.out.println("Shutting down Socket server!!");
       server.close();
    }
}
```

---

Еще конечно нужно не забывать про потоки, а также про сериализацию объектов и прочее прочее